# Is it possible, and if so how do you add external location data to LocationManager on Android?

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I have a WiFi device that outputs GPS location data over UDP Multicast. I want to create a background service for Android that will receive this location data and include it into LocationManager so other applications may use it's data.

I understand it is possible to use a test provider though this would require the application to include the permission *android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION* to use the location data. This seems like a very dirty way seeing as this location data isn't mocked.

I've also noticed quite a few Location Spoofing applications on the Android Market which tends to make me believe this is possible. Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this, short of rolling your own firmware or using the mock provider approach that you outline.

> I've also noticed quite a few Location Spoofing applications on the Android Market which tends to make me believe this is possible.

All seem to use the mock provider approach.